# Screwed up Render Settings

Tags: rendering

I was working with this wonderful tutorial, making a donut.
Render-mode and rendering was working fine until my objects suddenly turned invisible in Rendere-mode.
And when I render the image now, I get something that looks like an explosion of dough.

I don't want to start all over because what ever that was could happen again.

Please help :([image: Here is what I see]

Comment: Hello :). I'd say it's a combination of unsupported GPU drivers, and too large displacement on the donut. You can also share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I changed the render engine back to Eevee from Cycles. It did work before (the tutorial said to use cycles) but maybe it was too much at some point. Now it doesn't look as realistic but that's okay :)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from far away.
Try the funnel in the top right corner and enable "Disable in renders".
[image: Enable "Disable in renders"]

That way you can check your collections, whether they are enabled for rendering or not.

I've set my collection "DONT-RENDER" to "disable in renders". So, the red cube is shown in the viewport but "missing" in final render.

[image: Collection is not rendered]

Comment: Thank you :)
I actually changed the  render engine back to Eevee from Cycles and now I can see the objects. I don't know why it was too much for Cycles all of a sudden...